# Angular NX - Split single remote module into two routes

Tags: angular, routes, nrwl-nx

We received a change request to update the navigation within the application. Our app is a monorepo with module federation consisting of host and two remotes -> **Dashboard** and **Management**.

```javascript
// module-federation.manifest.json
{
  "management": "http://localhost:4201", 
  "dashboard": "http://localhost:4203"
}

// corresponding routes:
// http://our-app.com/management & http::/our-app.com/dashboard
```

Now we were tasked to move the **Settings** part out of the **Management** to a standalone route. I was hoping to do so without refactoring Settings modules to another lib. Is it actually doable?

This is what I tried so far:
**1. Added another module with the same address to manifest**

```json
{
  "management": "http://localhost:4201",
  "settings": "http://localhost:4201",
  "dashboard": "http://localhost:4203"
}
```

**2. Split management routes two to different RemoteEntry modules**

```typescript
// ### Management

const managementRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: RemoteEntryComponent,
    children: [
      // ...
      {
        path: 'reference-data',
        loadChildren: () => import('@remotes/management/reference-data').then((m) => m.ManagementReferenceDataFeatureShellModule),
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, RemoteEntryComponent, RouterModule.forChild(managementRoutes)]
})
export class ManagementRemoteEntryModule {}

// ### Settings

export const settingsRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: RemoteEntryComponent,
      {
        path: 'administration',
        loadChildren: () => import('@remotes/management/administration').then((m) => m.ManagementAdministrationModule),
        data: { breadcrumb: 'management-administration.navigation.me' }
      },
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, RemoteEntryComponent, RouterModule.forChild(settingsRoutes)]
})
export class SettingsRemoteEntryModule {}

// NOTE: Both routings handle both empty and wildcard routes, navigating to shown child routes (reference-data || administration). Omitted here to shorten the code
```

**3. Merged them in the AppRoutingModule which is then imported to Management's app.module** (the "main" one)

```typescript
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'management',
    loadChildren: () => import('./remote-entry/management-entry.module').then((m) => m.ManagementRemoteEntryModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'settings',
    loadChildren: () => import('./remote-entry/settings-entry.module').then((m) => m.SettingsRemoteEntryModule)
  },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'crd' }
];

export const routingConfiguration: ExtraOptions = {
  initialNavigation: 'enabledBlocking'
};

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, routingConfiguration)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

**4. Modified the `module-federation.config.js`, I try to expose module as an array**

```javascript
module.exports = {
  name: 'management',
  // There is no build nor compilation error, but I guess this is not a correct approach
  exposes: {
    // Before it was exposing just a single remote-entry module
    './Module': [
      'apps/management/src/app/remote-entry/management-entry.module.ts',
      'apps/management/src/app/remote-entry/settings-entry.module.ts'
    ],
  },
  shared: (name, config) => {
    if (name === 'luxon') {
      return {
        ...config,
        eager: true,
        version: '2.5.0'
      };
    }
  }
};
```

This doesn't work unfortunately. There error I'm getting is this one: `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: can't access property "\u0275mod", type is undefined`. Honestly, it's a crazy free-styling from my side and I pretty much how no idea if what I'm trying is even possible.

Is there actually a simple way, how to split the navigation to the same Remote (Management) but have its part accessible on two different 'root' routes (/management, /settings)?